# How to select version of function with a particular comptime parameter in gdb

Tags: gdb, zig

For example how to add a breakpoint to function `foo(true)` in line 100, which is `if (a) cat()`, of `src.zig` in gdb?

```
fn foo(comptime a: bool) void {
    if (a) cat()
    else mouse();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, zig does not seem to name comptime functions based on parameters

```
export fn demo() void {
    foo(true);
    foo(false);
}
```

→

```
// zig self-hosted (0.10.0):
call example.foo__anon_213
call example.foo__anon_214

// zig stage1 (0.9.0):
call foo
call foo.2
```

([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/34d7frTfs))

One way you could get around this is by putting a call to the function with the parameters you want somewhere you can find in order to determine what the symbol name is.